# Revit API - Reading all Project Warnings

Tags: c#, api, revit-api, revit

Is there any way to read all warning of the projects. I tried to follow some solution on the forums but I wasn't able to get the list of warning of the current project because it returns the list of default warnings that has nothing to do with the warning list of the current project.

I don't want to export the warning in HTML and read it from there, I rather like to read it from code. Is there any way I can achieve this via API?

Ideally, I'd like to read the warning in a hierarchy as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The [Revit 2018 API](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2018-api.html) implements a new method to [to get a list of reviewable warnings from a Document](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2018-api.html#3.18).

I just answered the same question in the [Revit API discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160) as well:

- [How to read all project warnings](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-to-read-all-project-warnings/m-p/7882964)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for taking the time to answer it. Really appreciate it :)